# Объединение локальных сетей двух роутеров

Tags: сеть, роутер

Имеются два роутера в локальной сети провайдера. Роутеры видят друг друга.

- IP адрес роутера **A**: **10.173.236.10** (модель роутера: Asus rtn-12d1)
- IP адрес сети роутера **A**: **192.168.1.1**

  ---
- IP адрес роутера **B**: **10.173.239.17** (Производитель Tp-link, модель не помню).
- IP адрес сети роутера **B**: **192.168.0.1**

Нужно чтобы компьютер из сети **A** (*IP адрес, например 192.168.1.192*) видел компьютер из сети **B** (*например 192.168.0.19*) как локальный, желательно без стороннего ПО ( ***виртуальные адаптеры*** в текущем контексте таковыми **не считаем** ), а если с ПО, то пожалуйста, объясните алгоритм его работы.

---

### P.S

Так же позволю себе задать вопрос личного характера. Видны ли у вас клиенты вашего же провайдера (как в данном примере). Если да, то не могли бы вы указать провайдера и район, в котором вы живёте. Ну и ещё пара подвопросов для опытных дядек ;)

1. Как часто встречается данная особенность (у всех ли провайдеров
   клиенты видны друг для друга ?).
2. Используется ли она обычными
       пользователями/ компаниями и опять же как часто.

   Всё это нужно для игры в Heroes 5 и проекта, если любопытно.

### **UPDATED**

Проверить доступность клиентов можно следующим способом (долго колебался, с одной стороны, скорее всего, человек, собравшийся ответить на заданный мною вопрос знает как это сделать, с другой стороны лишним не будет, плюс опять же кто нибудь может поправить/улучшить алгоритм):

1. Заходите в настройки роутера, если такового нет, то в настройки
   сетевого адаптера.
2. Копируем IP адрес основного шлюза.
3. Отправляем ping запрос на основной шлюз.

   - Если он ответил, то отправляем пинг запросы "соседним" шлюзам. Вот пример цикла для cmd: for /l %i in (1,1,254) do ping -n 1 <первый и второй октет шлюза>.%i.<4 октет шлюза (254)>
     Этого с лихвой хватит для ответа на мой вопрос.
   - Если он не ответил, то отправляем пинг запросы на клиентов, а не на основной шлюз. Вот пример цикла для cmd: for /l %i in (1,1,254) do ping -n 1 <Первые три октета>.%i .

Tracert между ними:

1. 192.168.1.1 [роутер A] --->
2. 178.173.25.33 [host-33.pool25] --->
3. 192.168.2.107 [sr-2.107] --->
4. 10.173.239.17 [внешний IP роутера B].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы хосты одной локальной сети получили доступ к хостам другой, нужно:

1. На первом роутере прописать статический маршрут во вторую сеть через внешний интерфейс второго роутера;
2. На втором роутере прописать статический маршрут в первую сеть через внешний интерфейс первого роутера;
3. Если внутренний интерфейс роутера сети не является дефолтным шлюзом хостов этой сети - на этих хостах прописать или раздать по DHCP маршрут во вторую сеть через внутренний интерфейс роутера сети.

После этого доступ к хостам другой сети по адресу появится.

Чтобы получить доступ по именам, а не адресам, необходимо дополнительно поднять сервис(ы) соответствующего пространства имён (DNS-сервер, WINS-сервер, LDAP-сервер и пр.) и прописать его (их) на хостах обеих сетей (или раздать по DHCP).

Comment: Это будет работать только в том случае, если роутеры своими внешними интерфейсами подключены в один сегмент сети. Т.е. должны видеть друг друга на уровне MAC. Но это вряд ли. Оборудование провайдера выполняет сегментацию сети и маршрутизацию между сегментами. В лучшем случае пакет, направленный в другую локалку, просто пропадёт, в худшем завернёт куда-нибудь в сеть провайдера и весь ваш интернет испортит. Только VPN поможет гарантированно соединить две (и более) локалки. Роутеры часто имеют возможности организации VPN.

Comment: _Это будет работать только в том случае, если роутеры своими внешними интерфейсами подключены в один сегмент сети. Т.е. должны видеть друг друга на уровне MAC._ Неправда Ваша. См. пункты 1 и 2. Если же они в разных подсетях - то да, не исключено, что потребуются настройки всей трассы между ними. Но о том, что посередине, нет ни полслова.

Comment: Добавил результат tracert-а, подходит ли это под "что посередине" не знаю, если нужны другие тесты вы попросите, сделаю. Я попробовал сделать статический маршрут на роутере A. В Asus-е задание статического маршрута имеет вид:(как блин, на следующую строку перейти ?). 1.IP адрес сети или хоста (вписал внешний IP роутера B). 2. Сетевая маска: 255.255.255.0 (или наша цель это хост ?). 3. Шлюз: ( 10.56.40.2  IP виртуального адаптера на моей машине, настройка хоть и ругалась, но поставил шлюз 192.168.1.1). 4. Интерфейс: WAN (Есть варианты с MAN и LAN).

Comment: Как я понял, теперь все пакеты с роутера B должны перенаправляться на виртуальный адаптер. Я попробовал отправить UDP пакет с помощью сокетов (забиндил сокеты на IP виртуального адаптера). Не сработало. Сейчас попробую с нормальным IP адресом (без виртуального адаптера)

Comment: @MihailDArsentev См. ответ Dldmyt. Этот не Ваш вариант. Asus может быть сервером VPN, судя по описанию в интернете. Посмотрите мануал по Tp-linkу. Выберете протокол VPN, который поддерживают оба роутера. PPTP обычно есть у всех. Если есть L2TP, то лучше сделать на нём.

Answer (score 1):

ну создайте пптп подключение, на одном настравиваешь пптп сервер, на втором клиента. потом на обоих настраиваете роутинг для сетей, которые раздаются , т.е. на первом пишется сеть второго, на втором -первого. как и куда тыкать не скажу, но асусы вроде более широконастраиваемые, лучше на  нем пптп сервербиндинг делать